# How to make transparent a bitmap corner

Tags: android, bitmap, transparency

I need to delete/remove/set transparent the top right corner of a bitmap (for example 10x10 px).

I have a bitmap of 60x60px and i want to delete the 10x10 top right corner. I was trying to do that with Canvas & Paint but i can't :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution...

Using Bitmap.getPixels and Bitmap.setPixels I solved the problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Answers should be more informative than this. And if you think that it answers the question, what you obviously do, you should also select it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new drawable and add the following line:

```
<corners android:topRightRadius="10px" />
```

Comment: i need to delete a square 10x10px from the top-right, no to make rounded corners.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just draw a 10x10 black or white (or whichever color) patch on your 60x60 image... The final result, it would appear to be what you exactly want it to look like!